# How to pause and restart an NSTimer when view disappears?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nstimer

I am using an `NSTimer` in my view class that is called every 15 seconds. My problem is, it is working properly, but my app is getting slow, because it is showing its performance to the whole app. So I want to pause the `NSTimer` when my view disappears from its superview and restart the timer when it appears. Please help me in solving the problem. Here is my code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    if(!Thread_bool)
    {
        //[spinner startAnimating];
        NSTimer *timer_new1=[[NSTimer alloc] init];
        timer_new1=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self                selector:@selector(threadMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        self.timer_new=timer_new1;
        [timer_new1 release];
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO];
        isEditing=NO;
        Thread_bool=YES;    
    }
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.timer_new invalidate];
    timer_new=nil;  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pausing an NSTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862743/pausing-an-nstimer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSTimer *timer_new1=[[NSTimer alloc] init];
timer_new1=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(threadMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
self.timer_new=timer_new1;
[timer_new1 release];
```

In first line you have alloced a timer and in second line another timer is created and assigned to `timer_new1`. So you lost the reference to the timer that was alloced in previous line and that is leaked. You don't need the first line alloc. Do this:

```
NSTimer *timer_new1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(threadMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And remove `[timer_new1 release];` (I am assuming that `self.timer_new` is retained). Also in `viewWillDisappear` do `self.timer_new = nil;` instead of `timer_new=nil;`. Adding that `self` will call the setter and correctly release the previous timer.

Comment: hi taskinoor its not working can u please give any suggestion on this..in fact i have return this code in viewWillAppear.if i tab another tab and if i return to same tab the timer is not working..please provide me any solution.

Comment: Add Thread_bool=NO in ViewWillDisappear or remove the if from viewWillAppear unless you are not setting Thread_bool=NO in anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You have two lines there which are creating an instance of `NSTimer`. The first is

```
    NSTimer *timer_new1 = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
```

and the second is

```
    timer_new1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(threadMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The `NSTimer` object created by the first line is retained, which you seem to be aware of because you're trying to release it later. However, the second line above is creating a *new* instance of NSTimer, which is **autoreleased**. When you do this, the first non-released `NSTimer` object is being leaked!

If you've set up your accessor method for `timer_new` to retain the timer, then delete the first line from above and **don't** release `timer_new1`.

Comment: hi charlie its not working can u please give any suggestion on this..in fact i have return this code in viewWillAppear.if i tab another tab and if i return to same tab the timer is not working..please provide me any solution

Comment: Well, when you first create the timer, you're setting Thread_bool to YES. So, unless you're setting it to NO somewhere else, the timer-setup code in viewWillAppear isn't going to run when you return from the other tab. Try removing the if() from viewWillAppear to see if it works then.